# Istio allowing external traffic through without ServiceEntry?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I deployed the sample sleep app.

```
kubectl apply -f samples/sleep/sleep.yaml  

kubectl get pods
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
httpbin-c868cf575-5tx5g   2/2     Running   0          2m56s
sleep-754684654f-k5ldh    2/2     Running   0          107s
```

```
kubectl get ServiceEntry --all-namespaces
No resources found.
```

Already I can exec in and curl an external site.

```
kubectl exec -it sleep-754684654f-k5ldh sh

/ # curl jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
...
]/ #
```

I expected to be unable to do this by default and for the external traffic to be blocked requiring `ServiceEntry` to allow it, but I can already make external requests. Did I miss a step?

Comment: I did not understand your problem. what you want to achieve? can you please elaborate your question.

Comment: It turns out this is the default behavior. https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/#envoy-passthrough-to-external-services Had to change `global.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode` from `ALLOW_ANY` => `REGISTRY_ONLY`.

Comment: are you able to make https call outside mesh? Any clue for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640466/kubernetes-pods-can-not-make-https-request-after-deploying-istio-service-mesh

Comment: @atkayla is problem still exist? HAve you changed global.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode to REGISTRY_ONLY?